# Does Silverlight 4 require .NET 4?

Tags: .net-4.0, silverlight-4.0

Do Silverlight 4 applications require that they target .NET 4.

With the delay in .NET 4 and Visual Studio 2010; can I still get the advantages of Silverlight 4 running against the .NET 3.5 framework?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Silverlight does not require *any* version of .NET (or, put another way, it includes its own sorta-kinda version of .NET; at any rate, it doesn't need any version of the *full* .NET runtime).  It is a completely independent runtime.